# 3rd party app installed, shows in site contents, does not show as available to insert on page

Tags: app

Working with a 3rd party app called Announcement Slider - I have used this before successfully on other site pages. I am the site owner and working on a 365 platform. Previous and current attempt include app installation on a Classic page.

This time when I installed the app (marked it as trusted), it appears in the site contents, but when I go to insert the app on the page, it does not show as an available option.

Looking for ideas for a work-around. I have tried deleting the app the reinstalling it with no success. Would prefer to not change apps, to stay style consistent with my other sites.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

On which type of page you try to add your web part ?(Modern or classic page)?

May be you try to add this app part on a modern page, and this app is only available on classic page

Comment: Classic page, same as I have on the previous pages

Comment: I just tested, I could add the app and add the Webpart on a page without any problem... Sorry, I have no idea for your problem

Comment: You can't select the web part (because the WP is not visible in the list) when you whant to add it, Or you can add it to the page, but you can't configure it ?

Comment: WP is not visible in the list